Can you fold a square into a rectangular prism with the same surface area as the original square without cutting it?
This question arose after I saw this reddit post. The QP wanted to find what size blanket they needed to cover their 46cm x 36cm x 99cm rectangular bird cage.
I saw one person answer that they needed to just find a blanket with the same surface area as the bird cage, which would be (if you wanted to cover the bottom as well)
$$2(lw + lh + wh) = 19548 \mathrm{~cm}^2$$
with $(l,w,h) = (46, 36, 99)$ cm.
This would correspond to a square blanket with side lengths equal to $\left\lceil\sqrt {19548\text {cm}^2} \right \rceil \approx $ 140 cm
If you ignore the bottom of the bird cage (one of the $lw$) then you only need a side length of $\left\lceil\sqrt {17892\text {cm}^2} \right \rceil \approx $ 134 cm
This got me thinking though: Is it actually possible to fold a square blanket into a rectangular prism without cutting it? When rectangular prisms are unfolded, the net of the rectangular prism is usually shown like this:

Which would require cutting and stitching of the square blanket into rectangular sections that correspond to the different sides of the bird cage.
The way I thought about the problem is this:
When the square blanket is centered on the top of the bird cage, you want it to "droop down" enough to cover the top of the bird cage and the sides.
In each direction from the top center of bird cage, the blanket needs to extend out $\frac{\max  (46, 36)}{2}$ cm = 23 cm to cover the top
The blanket then needs to droop down another 99 cm to cover the full height of the bird cage, so from the center the blanket needs to be 23 + 99 = 122 cm long, so the side length of the square blanket needs to be 2*122 cm = 244 cm long to guarantee all parts of the cage are covered.
If you relax the blanket to be rectangular instead of square, then it needs to extend 2*(46/2 + 99) = 244 cm in one direction, and 2*(36/2 + 99) = 234 cm in the other direction, giving a 244 x 234 cm rectangular blanket.
This is a lot bigger than the estimate given by using the bird cage's surface area. It would be nice to use a smaller blanket if possible because it would cost less. But I'm not sure if it is possible to fold up the smaller square blanket in such a way that it covers the bird cage?

The sum of the angles around each corner of the prism is $270^\circ$. The only way to produce this from a non-overlapping blanket is by having each corner of the prism coincide with a corner of the blanket. But the prism has twice as many corners as the blanket. Therefore it can't be done.
